# C# filter out duplicates from list of custom objects based on list attribute

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<IPInfo>` of custom `IPInfo` objects. I need to filter out duplicates based on two attributes from this class.

Here is a class:

```
class IPInfo
{
    public String TRADE_DATE; 
    public String CUSTOMER_NAME;
    public List<String> ORIGINAL_IP;
    public List<String> LOGON_IP = new List<String>();
}
```

The `List<IPInfo> fields` has records with the same `CUSTOMER_NAME` and `LOGON_IP`. I want to remove them, so that the entry with the same `CUSTOMER_NAME` is guaranteed to have different `LOGON_IP`.

I tried LINQ based on other posted answers. But this code is not compiling.

```
    private static List<IPInfo> selectFields(ref List<IPInfo> fields)
    {
        var distinct = fields.GroupBy(x => new { x.CUSTOMER_NAME, x.LOGON_IP })
                .Select(y => new IPInfo()
                {
                    TRADE_DATE = y.Key.TRADE_DATE,
                    CUSTOMER_NAME = y.Key.CUSTOMER_NAME,
                    ORIGINAL_IP = y.ToList(),
                    LOGON_IP = y.ToList()
                }
                ).ToList();

        return distinct;
    }
```

Please give me some hints.

`Trade_date`     `Customer_name`      `Original_IP`       `Logon_IP`

[image]

Comment: MoreLINQ's `DistinctBy`

Comment: You can use _HashSet_ or _Dictionary_

Comment: @Enigmativity why?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno - `ref` makes your code hard to reason about. Changes to local variables can happen in places you don't expect.

Comment: I am using `List` from another function `Foo(...ref List<IPInfo> fields)` and from this `Foo` function I want to refine `fields`. So private `selectFields` is serving this purpose. But I can do it without `ref`. Please advise me how.

Comment: Simply remove `ref`. That is literally all you need to do to stop using it. It isn't doing anything useful for you, so remove it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a crack:

```
private static List<IPInfo> selectFields(ref List<IPInfo> fields)
{
    var distinct =
        fields
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.TRADE_DATE, x.CUSTOMER_NAME })
            .Select(y => new IPInfo()
            {
                TRADE_DATE = y.Key.TRADE_DATE,
                CUSTOMER_NAME = y.Key.CUSTOMER_NAME,
                ORIGINAL_IP = y.SelectMany(x => x.ORIGINAL_IP).Distinct().ToList(),
                LOGON_IP = y.SelectMany(x => x.LOGON_IP).Distinct().ToList()
            })
            .ToList();

    return distinct;
}
```

Comment: This code combined the records. Instead of many similar records I have a huge one now. How can I remove the duplicates? Maybe shouldn't use LINQ?

Comment: @user2376997 - Are you are wanting to also remove duplicate IPs? I just edited my answer to do so.

Answer (score 4):

You can try `GroupBy` and `First` (if we have a *group* of duplicates, we should take *first* item only).

Another issue is how to group by `List<T>` (`LOGON_IP` is a list); assuming that `LOGON_IP` are equal if and only if they have same items in the same order we can 
turn `LOGON_IP` into `string` with a help of `string.Join`; if order within `LOGON_IP` doesn't matter, we can use

```
string.Join(" ", x.LOGON_IP.OrderBy(ip => ip))
```

**Code:**

```
private static List<IPInfo> selectFields(ref List<IPInfo> fields)
{
    var distinct = fields 
      .GroupBy(x => new { x.CUSTOMER_NAME, ips = string.Join(" ", x.LOGON_IP) })
      .Select(chunk => chunk.First())
      .ToList();

    return distinct;
}
```

**Edit:** In case we don't want to return duplicates *at all* (i.e. if item has a duplicate we should remove *all its occurrences*), let's check `Count`:

```
private static List<IPInfo> selectFields(ref List<IPInfo> fields)
{
    var distinct = fields 
      .GroupBy(x => new { x.CUSTOMER_NAME, ips = string.Join(" ", x.LOGON_IP) })
      .Where(chunk => chunk.Count() == 1)
      .Select(chunk => chunk.First())
      .ToList();

    return distinct;
}
```

Comment: This code is not removing duplicates. All records are still in the `List`. How to remove them?

Comment: All records are still in place. I am calling it from another function `fields = selectFields(ref fields);`. Consequently I export to .xls file and records are duplicated as in my picture above

Comment: @user2376997: I see, the cause of misbehaviour is that we grouping by list (`x.LOGON_IP`), let's convert `List<string>` into `string` with a help of `String.Join`

Comment: It is not compiling